# If $G$ is a group and $[G:Z(G)]=4$, show that $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I want to show that if $G$ is a group and $[G:Z(G)]=4$, then $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I know I can do this by showing that $|G/Z(G)|=4$. For then $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. The former group is cyclic, so then $G/Z(G)$ would have to be cyclic. But if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian, whence $Z(G)=G$, whence $[G:Z(G)]=1\neq4$. Therefore, $G/Z(G)$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Any suggestions on how to show that $|G/Z(G)|=4$?

Comment: "If $Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian"? That's not true (Take the group of quaternions $Q_8$). Perhaps you mean, $G/Z(G)$ in that statement?

Comment: The dihedral group of order $8$ has center of order $2$. So your statement is not true. [Reference](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_dihedral_group:D8)

Comment: Indeed I do; thanks for pointing it out! That makes my post very confusing, so I will edit it.

Comment: This is exercise 46 in chapter 9 in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you mean you wish to prove that $G/Z(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, because otherwise your statement implies that $|G| = 16$.

Assuming this, begin by showing that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then the group $G$ must be abelian. Hence, since there is only one non-cyclic group of order $4$, the result follows immediately.

Comment: You are right, of course! If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then for any $a \in G$, $Z(G)a\in G/Z(G)$, and we have $Z(G)a=Z(G)d^{k_1}$ for some $k_1$, whence $a=c_1d^{k_1}$ for some $c_1\in Z(G)$. Similarly, for any $b \in G$, $b=c_2d^{k_2}$ for some $c_2 \in Z(G)$ and some $k_2$. But then $ab=c_1d^{k_1}c_2d^{k_2}=c_2d^{k_2}c_1d^{k_1}$, because $c_1$ and $c_2$ commute with all elements of $G$. But how can I be sure that $|G/Z(G)|=4$?

Comment: @JohnIsidore It is a general fact that $$[G: H] = \frac{|G|}{|H|} = \left|G/H\right|$$ whenever $H \leq G$ and $G$ is finite.

Comment: Silly me. I was still thinking along the lines of the original post and shooting for showing that $|Z(G)|=4$.