# Groups with large centers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider any finite $2-$group $G$ and let $|G:C(G)|=4$. What can be said about $G$? is there any classification of these groups?

By $C(G)$ I mean center of $G$ and by $|G:H| = |G|/|H|$.

Comment: $G/Z(G)$ would have to be the Klein 4-group.

Answer (score 3):

This class of groups is quite restricted and should admit a full classification, or something very close to it.

Let $G$ be a group with center of index $4$, and $Z$ be its center. Then $G$ is generated by $Z$, together with two extra elements, say $x$ and $y$. Moreover, $G$ is completely determined by the choice of $Z$ together with the choice of three additional elements of $Z$, corresponding to $x^2$, $y^2$, and $[x,y]$.

EDIT:
Note that this is a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177693/classification-of-2-groups-with-center-of-index-4

In a comment there, Derek Holt claims that the only such groups are direct or central product of $D_8$ or $Q_8$ with an abelian $2$-group. That doesn't seem right though. There are examples of order $16$ that are not of this type, for example the non-trivial semidirect product $C_4\rtimes C_4$.

I think what is true is that it suffices to classify the case when $G=\langle x,y\rangle$, and then the general result can be obtained by taking central products with examples that arise in this case.

EDIT 2: Let $z=[x,y]\in Z$. Then $x^y=xz$ so  $x=x^{y^2}=(xz)^y=xz^2$, so $z^2=1$. This shows that the derived subgroup has order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Remark: $2$-groups with $G/Z(G)\cong C_2\times C_2$ may still be too hard to classify.

The second remark, by the Lord, can be found here:

[If $G$ is a group and $[G:Z(G)]=4$, show that $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475631/if-g-is-a-group-and-gzg-4-show-that-g-zg-is-isomorphic-to-mathbb)

Comment: It is trivial that $G/Z(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. In my question it is given that $G$ is $2-$ group and so it is interesting to classify them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question, but @Dietrich Burde is probably correct that this is likely not an easy problem.  Your condition implies that the group has class $2$, and I'm not aware of a general classification for $2$-groups of class $2$, though your condition is admittedly stronger.

For reasons I don't fully understand, there seems to have been better progress classifying groups by coclass. (If $G$ has order $p^n$ and class $c$, its *coclass* is $n-c$, which is the difference between its derived length and nilpotency class.)  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coclass), for example. Depending upon where you are coming at this from, that might be an interesting avenue for you to look into.

Having said that, there is a complete classification of *two-generator* $p$-groups of class $2$, described [here](https://science.utm.my/nizasarmin/files/2016/07/Two-Generator-p-Groups-of-Nilpotency-Class-Two-A-Review.pdf), which is fairly recent.  You might be able to fish out those among them with central quotient $C_2\times C_2$.