# If $G$ is a non-abelian finite group, then $|Z(G)| \leq \frac {1}{4} |G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, quotient-group

I know this is question has been asked  several times on here, only hints given ,but just want to check if I have the right idea.

My attempt:
Suppose G is non abelian finite group and $|Z(G)| \gt \frac {1}{4} |G|$.
Since Z(G) is a subgroup of G then it’s order must divide that of G , i.e it could be of size |G|/3 , |G|/2 or |G|  .That  means the quotient group G/Z has order 1 ,2 or 3 . If equal to 1 that implies Z(G)=G so abelian , and also since 2 and 3 are prime numbers that means G/Z is cyclic which also implies it’s abelian. Which leads to a contradiction.
Is that right? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Indeed the minimum size of the inner automorphism group when it is non-trivial is $V$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686286/groups-with-large-centers).

Comment: @Parcly Taxel thanks , also one quick question could one just define any quotient group as simply the left coset ?

Comment: _If_ the quotient is defined in the first place, then yes, since left coset equals right coset for normal subgroups.

Comment: Say G is abelian then G/H quotient group would be abelian aswell , but is there a case when G isn’t abelian and G/H is ?

Comment: Please ask a new question with this.

Comment: Also, it is because if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: The last part is not very clear. If $G/Z$ is cyclic, then of course it is abelian, but more importantly, it implies $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @Hongyi Huang isn’t that what I said?

Comment: @verret yep I meant to say G is abelian